# How do you return the column names of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would I return the column names of a table using SQL Server 2008? i.e. a table contains these columns- id, name, address, country and I want to return these as data.

Answer (score 446, accepted):

Not sure if there is an easier way in 2008 version.

```
USE [Database Name]
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourSchemaName'
```

Comment: What is the 'YourSchemaName'?

Comment: 'YourSchemaName' is the schema for the table you're querying against.  Example: dbo.myTable, 'dbo' is the schema that 'myTable' belongs to.  Schemas make it easier to assign permissions to a grouping instead of each table individually.  See this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062075/why-do-table-names-in-sql-server-start-with-dbo

Comment: Dont forget on USE DatabaseName command otherwise you can search in master or different database than you want to

Comment: SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'

Answer (score 128):

This is the easiest way

```
exec sp_columns [tablename]
```

Comment: If your schema is not dbo, you must pass it as an additional parameter. exec sp_columns [TableName], @table_owner = [schema]

Answer (score 35):

Something like this?

```
sp_columns @table_name=your table name
```

Answer (score 17):

One method is to query syscolumns:

```
select
   syscolumns.name as [Column],
   syscolumns.xusertype as [Type],
   sysobjects.xtype as [Objtype]
from 
   sysobjects 
inner join 
   syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
where sysobjects.xtype = 'u'
and   sysobjects.name = 'MyTableName'
order by syscolumns.name
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fully write out the join (sysobjects so inner join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id)?  This seems like a lazy answer at the expense of performance. I could be wrong...

Comment: @Losbear changed it PS: Not lazy, it's just code from 8 years ago. :) In old times (I used SQL Server starting at version 4.2), I used to write SQL queries this way. no performance issues.

Answer (score 13):

try this

```
select * from <tablename> where 1=2
```

...............................................

Comment: Interesting ,but what is the logic behind it?

Comment: @nilakanthasinghdeo, the logic is that it will always return zero rows with `WHERE 1=2` and it will still return the column meta-data. If using a programmatic interface such as ODBC, then this column info is accessible as a list/array from the cursor object within the program, which is what I was looking for. It might not make sense in a pure SQL context, but is a succinct approach when connecting to a database via Python/Java/C/etc.

Answer (score 10):

This seems a bit easier then the above suggestions because it uses the **OBJECT_ID()** function to locate the table's id.  Any column with that id is part of the table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM syscolumns 
 WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('YOUR_TABLE')
```

I commonly use a similar query to see if a column I know is part of a newer version is present.  It is the same query with the addition of {AND name='YOUR_COLUMN'} to the where clause.

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
          FROM syscolumns 
         WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('YOUR_TABLE') 
           AND name='YOUR_COLUMN'
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Column found'
END
```

Answer (score 7):

I use

```
SELECT st.NAME, sc.NAME, sc.system_type_id
FROM sys.tables st
INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
WHERE st.name LIKE '%Tablename%'
```

Answer (score 7):

The following seems to be like the first suggested query above but sometime you have to specify the database to get it to work. Note that the query should also work without specifying the TABLE_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM   YOUR_DB_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just try this:

> right click on the table  -> Script Table As -> Create To -> New Query Editor
>   Window?

The entire list of columns are given in the script. Copy it and use the fields as necessary.

Comment: The author likely wanted to know how to get the column names from the table programmatically for use in a stored procedure or other script.

Comment: The answer states `"I want to return these as data"`, while your answer will get the values, it's likely the OP wants the data at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

```
USE [Database]

SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       TABLE_SCHEMA,
       [Column_Name],
       [Data_type]
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the syscolumns.colid value is the same as the 'ORDINAL_POSITION' value returned as part of sp_columns, but in what follows I am using it that way - hope I'm not misinforming...

Here's a slight variation on some of the other answers I've found - I use this because the 'position' or order of the column in the table is important in my application - I basically need to know 'What is column (n) called?'

sp_columns returns a whole bunch of extraneous stuff, and I'm handier with a select than T-SQL functions, so I went this route:

```
select    
  syscolumns.name, 
  syscolumns.colid    
from     
  sysobjects, syscolumns  
where 
  sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id and   
  sysobjects.xtype = 'u' and   
  sysobjects.name = '<YOUR_TABLE>' 
order by syscolumns.colid
```

Comment: I used this method for a long time, but was advised against it. In fact I hit the exact problem I was told I might...it's more likely that new versions of MSSQL will change the syntax. For example it used to be sys.object and sys.columns in the versions I first used this technique on. Supposedly the schema and stored procedure methods are more proof against this... not sure, but so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_GetColumnName]      
        @TableName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN   
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        IF (@TableName IS NOT NULL) 
            select ORDINAL_POSITION OrderPosition,COLUMN_NAME ColumnName from information_schema.columns 
             where table_name =@TableName
             order by ORDINAL_POSITION
    END
END
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  But it looks like this question already got a satisfactory answer about three years ago... Also, when posting code, use the {} to highlight it.  Have a look at the FAQ, it has some good info on getting started here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

While @Gulzar Nazim's answer is great, it is probably easier to include the *database name* in the query, which could be achieved by the following SQL.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'you-table-name' AND TABLE_CATALOG='your-database-name'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to print all column names; You can also modify the code to print other details in whichever format u like

```
    declare @Result varchar(max)='
            '
            select @Result=@Result+''+ColumnName+'
            '
            from
            (
                select
                    replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
                    column_id ColumnId
                from sys.columns col
                    join sys.types typ on
                        col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
                where object_id = object_id('tblPracticeTestSections')
            ) t
            order by ColumnId
            print @Result
```

**Output**

```
column1
column2
column3
column4
```

To use the same code to print the table and its column name as C# class use the below code:

```
    declare @TableName sysname = '<EnterTableName>'
    declare @Result varchar(max) = 'public class ' + @TableName + '
    {'

    select @Result = @Result + '
        public static string ' + ColumnName + ' { get { return "'+ColumnName+'"; } }
    '
    from
    (
        select
            replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
            column_id ColumnId
        from sys.columns col
            join sys.types typ on
                col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
        where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
    ) t
    order by ColumnId

    set @Result = @Result  + '
    }'

    print @Result
```

**Output:**

```
 public class tblPracticeTestSections
 {
   public static string column1 { get { return "column1"; } }

   public static string column2{ get { return "column2"; } }

   public static string column3{ get { return "column3"; } }

   public static string column4{ get { return "column4"; } }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @col= COALESCE(@col, '') + ',' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  Table_name = 'MxLocations';
SELECT @col;
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you are working with postgresql there is a possibility that more than one schema may have table with same name in that case apply the below query

```
SELECT column_name, data_type 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name' AND table_schema = 'your_schema_name’;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use a query like Martin Smith mentioned, just little shorter:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [SysColumns is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx), use [`Sys.All_Columns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx):

```
Select  
 ObjectName       = Object_Name(Object_ID)  
,T.Name  
,C.*  
,T.*  
From   
           Sys.All_Columns C  
Inner Join Sys.Types       T  On T.User_Type_Id = C.User_Type_Id  
Where [Object_ID] = Object_ID('Sys.Server_Permissions')  
--Order By Name Asc
```

`Select * From Sys.Types` will yield  `user_type_id = ID` of the type. This is unique within the database. For system data types: `user_type_id = system_type_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I got here 15 years too late, but with some success I just did:

```sql
SELECT TOP(0) * FROM <table_name>
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score -3):

```
set fmtonly on
select * from yourTable
```