# Obtain column names from SQL Server via Perl DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I can run

```
sp_columns MY_TABLE
```

to get all the column names (under `COLUMN_NAME`). However, how can I obtain the same information using Perl DBI?

In particular, I tried

```
my $result = $dbh->selectall_hashref("sp_columns MY_TABLE", 'COLUMN_NAME');
```

hoping that the column names would be the keys of the returned hash.

In fact, even if that's successful, that's not what I want as I need to preserve the order of columns in that table. So I tried

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("sp_columns $table");
$sth->execute();
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    # process @row;
}
```

But neither works. I got the error message of

```
DBD::Sybase::db selectall_hashref failed: Server message number=102 severity=15 state=1 line=1 server=XXXX text=Incorrect syntax near '.'
```

I also referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/sql-server-how-do-you-return-the-column-names-from-a-table). Apparently the following query does *NOT* work in my Management Studio:

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = MY_TABLE
```

with the error message of

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'information_schema.columns'.
```

Please help? Thx!

Comment: If you're getting invalid object name on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS it may be that you don't have permission. If your collation is case sensitive you also need to use all caps. But it definitely exists in SQL Server.

Comment: Nonesense. information_schema is available in many databases including MS SQL Server.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is a mysql5 thing. It isnt available in mysql 4.1

Comment: So apparently @Emtucifor is correct that the collation is case sensitive on my server hence after changing everything to upper case, I got the query working, and I was able to extract the column names that way. Thx everyone.

Comment: Converting my comment to an answer...

Comment: @DVK I'm sorry to say this, but that's incorrect. INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is a SQL Server thing, too. In the same schema are CHECK_CONSTRAINTS, COLUMN_DOMAIN_USAGE, COLUMN_PRIVILEGES, CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE, CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE, DOMAIN_CONSTRAINTS, DOMAINS, KEY_COLUMN_USAGE, PARAMETERS, REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS, ROUTINE_COLUMNS, ROUTINES, SCHEMATA, TABLE_CONSTRAINTS, TABLE_PRIVILEGES, TABLES, VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE, and VIEWS. Some of these may be SQL 2005 and up only, but many are available in SQL 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting invalid object name on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS it may be that you don't have permission. If your collation is case sensitive you also need to use all caps. But it definitely exists in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

The returned column names are an attribute of a prepared statement, so you can use:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:DBMS:...','','');
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM SomeTable");
```

and now `$sth->{NAME}` (an array reference) contains the names of the columns (as aliased, etc).

Comment: I think $sth->{NAME}  must be called at a certain point in time (before data are accessed in a loop). It goes out of scope early, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @knb: that might depend on the driver.  For sure, it doesn't go out of scope in DBD::Informix until the handle is destroyed.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler: I was talking about DBD::Sybase in particular. Maybe once I tried to access $sth->{NAME} after the subroutine where $sth was created went out of scope. Wasnt able to look up the code example yesterday (and today, neither).

Comment: @jonathan-leffler: You have to $sth->execute() before you can get $sth->{NAME}. I usually add a "WHERE 1=0" also if that sort of info is all I want. (I believe) Some db's return the entire result set to some client layer before fetching.

Comment: @runrig: you may be right for some DBD's; DBD::Informix does not require execute before you get the column names.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler: Ah, right, some DBD's is what the docs say. I did not know that about Informix, though it does make sense for databases that have an actual "prepare" phase.

Comment: @runrig: I do know about DBD::Informix - I wrote it.  I can't answer for the other DBD modules so definitively.

Answer (score 3):

See the [catalogue methods](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#Catalog_Methods) that DBI supports. In particular, I expect you want table_info.