# How can I SELECT that lists all the field names and their types for a given Db Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: How do you return the column names from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/sql-server-how-do-you-return-the-column-names-from-a-table)

Assume that I have Data base table: *LunchMenuItems*

For the MS-SQL Server, how can I write a TSQL query that :

Lists all the column names and their types in *LunchMenuItems* table?

Comment: @Mythje yes there is in the DATA_TYPE column

Comment: The documentation for the information schema is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

This Information can be found in `information_schema.columns`.

#### Sample

```
select column_name, DATA_TYPE from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'LunchMenuItems'
```

#### More Information

- [COLUMNS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933218%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)