# Insert into command with Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: How do you return the column names from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/sql-server-how-do-you-return-the-column-names-from-a-table)

I wanted to know if there was a way to insert the Column names from on table into a field in another table.

I have a new table where the column names of the old table is now a parameter in the new table.

ie.

```
old table
[id] [name] [name2] [name3]
  1    x      x       x

new table
[id] [name type]
 1    name
 2    name2
 3    name3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return the columns of a specified table:

```
SELECT COL.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    information_schema.columns COL
WHERE 
    (COL.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_name') AND
    (CO.TABLE_NAME = 'table_name')
```

You can use the result set and insert it into a temporary table, or use it for whatever you need.

**Note**: I ran it on SQL Server 2008, but it should work on 2005 as well.

Comment: Great! Didnt think about that method. Thanks Diego!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'OldTable'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `SELECT INTO` a new table or a temp table. Example below is a temp table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
into #temp
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourSchema' AND
    TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'

select *
from #temp

drop table #temp
```