# Get Select Fields with Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex

We are looking for a regular expression that returns the names of the SQL-Select Fields:
**1 fixedValue Custno CustName** (can be separated with , ; etc.)

```
select 
1, 
'test' as fixedvalue , 
tbl.s_no as custno , 
ltrim(rtrim(isnull(tbl.s_name1, '') + ' ' + isnull(tbl.s_name2, ''))) as custname 
from tbl
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Not quite clear. Where is this regular expression in your example? Why do you need to get the columns? Which DB are you using?

Comment: There is no Regex because we don't have one. The example above is a string where we need a regex for that matches the column names. The select should not be executed we're just trying to get the column names.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification. Which database are you using?

Comment: We're using SQL-Server 2012

Comment: OK. How about returning a result set of the column names. Would that do? If so, you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/sql-server-how-do-you-return-the-column-names-from-a-table

Comment: I'm not executing the SQL (not working in a Management Studio), it is just a string where i want to use the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

See if this wroks for you

```
\w*\s*as\s([a-zA-Z]*)
```

Comment: preg_match_all returns the following, is it possible to get the "1" too ? 
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  as fixedvalue
            [1] => s_no as custno
            [2] =>  as custname
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fixedvalue
            [1] => custno
            [2] => custname
        )

)