# How to select rows with the same criteria in multiple columns?

Tags: sql

Will there be any other ways instead of writing the same criteria multiple times?

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployees E
WHERE E.CurrentAddress LIKE '%dan%' OR 
E.Email1 LIKE '%dan%' OR
E.Email2 LIKE '%dan%' OR 
E.LatinName LIKE '%dan%'
```

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good.
what I mean is, is there a way to simplify the '%dan%'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways, but yours is probably the most efficient already. You could always do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblEmployees
WHERE CurrentAddress + Email1 + Email2 + LatinName LIKE '%dan%'
```

If some of the columns are `NULL`, you could use `ISNULL([field], '')`.

However, as @MitchWheat pointed out, it's not exactly the same query, since a field could end
by `d` and the next field could start by `an`.

Comment: Thanks. what if I want to use all the columns in tblEmployees?

Comment: @BongDaleap Well, if you are not willing to hard-code all the columns, you could always build a dynamic SQL statement by fetching the column names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/sql-server-how-do-you-return-the-column-names-from-a-table

Comment: that's not the same query:   CurrentAddress ends in 'd', email1 starts with 'an' for example

Answer (score 0):

If none of the values are `NULL`, you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblEmployees E
WHERE concat(E.CurrentAddress, ' ', E.email1, ' ', E.email2, ' ', E.LatinName) LIKE '%dan%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with plalx on this one, but if you're worried about typing '%dan%' multiple times, use a variable:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @p_search NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @p_search = '%dan%'

    SELECT *
    FROM tblEmployees E
    WHERE E.CurrentAddress LIKE @p_search
        OR E.Email1 LIKE @p_search
        OR E.Email2 LIKE @p_search
        OR E.LatinName LIKE @p_search
END
GO
```