# Get array of database field names in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

What's the simplest way to get a string array of database field names?  I tried using `SHOW COLUMNS` but I couldn't get it to work.

I'm currently doing it this way:

```
private List<string> GetDBFieldNames()
{
    List<string> dbFieldNames = new List<string>();
    try {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = d.connectDB();
        String query = "select * from my_table";
        SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd.Fill(dt);

        foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
            dbFieldNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {}

    return dbFieldNames;
}
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You tagged your question with "MySQL" but `System.Data.SqlClient` is for MS SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry yes it is MS SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to get the colmn names ist to select them from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600457/3451056). You can go with the following SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='SchemaName'
```

Comment: Thanks but would I still fill a datatable with this?  Doesn't work if I just replace the sql statement

Comment: You just get the column names. Did you replace TabelName and SchemaName? Please update your code example.

Comment: I got it working.  I just needed to get the rows instead of column names with `string field = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();`