# DynamicsAX - Get SQL Statement by tablename

Tags: c#, sql, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I'd like to create a class in AX2012 which I can call from Ax2012 Business Connector that allows me to generate the SQL statement for a specified table.

The method I implemented at the class is:

```
client server public static str getTableStatement(str tableName)
{    
     OMInternalOrganization org;
     select generateOnly org;
     info(org.getSQLStatement());
     return org.getSQLStatement();
}
```

My question is: how can I now use the parameter tableName instead of the static assignment of OMInternalOrganization.

It would be also fine to find another way of getting the SQL statement.

I'm a .Net Developer and have nearly NO experience with X++ development.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "It would be also fine to find another way of getting the SQL statement" - what is the current logic of your `getSQLStatement` method?

Comment: @10p - getSQLStatement is base 2012. I was unaware of it as well.

Comment: my current logic was taking the tablename from the ax metadataservice and building the sql statement based on this.
I had problems with inheritance here so i found that it is possible from AX to get the statement, but i didn't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SysDictTable::makeRecord`.

```
client server public static str getTableStatement(str tableName)
{
    Common buffer;
    ;

    buffer = SysDictTable::newName(tableName).makeRecord();
    select generateOnly buffer;
    info(buffer.getSQLStatement());
    return buffer.getSQLStatement();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the list of the table fields, you can use the following code.

```
client server public static str getTableStatement(str _tableName)
{
    SysDictTable dt = SysDictTable::newName(_tableName);
    str ret;    

    if (dt)
    {
        ret = strFmt('SELECT * FROM %1', dt.name(DbBackend::Sql));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

P.S. You can modify the code if you're only interested in the name of the table in SQL Server (not in AX).

Comment: thanks for the information about dbBackend::SQL
I´m not sure if this one would work with table inheritance.

Comment: For derived tables it would always return the base table name, because only 1 table is used in SQL Server database for table inheritance hierarchy. As I mentioned, it could be useful if you don't need the field names to be returned (i.e. you already know the fields you need to use or can get this info elsewhere).

Comment: Ah okay.
Just for completeness, how could i get all the SQL-Field names for a single table?

Comment: In AX - by using `DictTable` and `DictField` classes, and `DictField.name(DbBackend::Sql)`. 
In SQL Server - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/