# How to check whether the table contains a particular column or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to check whether the table contains a particular column or not?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/sql-server-how-do-you-return-the-column-names-from-a-table

Comment: information_schema.columns! (Or try if select column from table raises an error or not...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you return the column names of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/how-do-you-return-the-column-names-of-a-table)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query the information schema tables for this kind of information and much more.

In your case something like this would be useful:

```
select
* 
from
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where
    table_schema = '<your schema>'
    and
    table_name = '<your table>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if exists
(select * from sys.columns
 where Name = N'columnName' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tableName'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a particular column.

```
IF EXISTS(
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'TableName'
AND [COLUMN_NAME] = 'ColumnName'
AND [TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'SchemaName')
BEGIN
PRINT 'Your Column Exists'
END
```