# Separated (*) All Columns using delimeter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to separate (*) all columns I get from selecting temp table into single strings. Without knowing column name.

Let's say the record only one.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | ...Cols |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Res1 | Res2 | Res3 | ...Rest |

Separate all columns into single column

| CommaSeparatedCol. |
| --- |
| Res1,Res2,Res3, ...Rest |

I'm using SQL Server.

I was thinking using variable and looping through result and get each column values and assign to variable, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What happens when your table was 2 or more rows?

Comment: here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812941/how-to-create-comma-delimited-list-from-table-with-dynamic-columns

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that if your table has multiple rows, you want multiple rows, you could do something like this. Note that all your values will be **implicitly** converted to a `varchar` or `nvarchar`, and so you are are allowing SQL Server to determine what it'll be.

*Assuming* you're on a recent version of SQL Server you can do this (if not, you'll need to use the old `FOR XML PATH` method for `STRING_AGG` and `CONCAT` for `CONCAT_WS` (and `STUFF` with both):

```sql
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname = N'YourSchema',
        @TableName sysname = N'YourTable';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT CONCAT_WS('','',' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.[name]),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.column_id) + N') AS YourColumns' + @CRLF +
              N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N';'
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE s.[name] = @SchemaName
  AND t.[name] = @TableName

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Does it work using temp table?

Comment: No, not as written, @HafizhanAlWafi , because they aren't created in the same database, and because they have different name in the `sys` objects. Though that's a very late curve ball; you'll need to amend the above a little if you want it to work with Temporary tables instead/as well.