# SELECT rows that have specified values in one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table on my **SQL Server 2012**:

```
ID Name Status Address Phone
1  Tom    I       U      D
2  Joe    D       U      D
3  Pam    D       I      U
4  Ken    U       U      U
```

How do I select the rows with '**I**' in one of the columns? for example, I expect the query to return 1st and 3rd row from the table.

I know the query below works however I need a query that does not specify the column names as I need to deal with a table with more than 20 columns.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Status = 'I' or Address = 'I' or Phone = 'I')
```

Comment: Is there a way of using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns so I don't have to specify all column name explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use XML:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM tab t2 WHERE t.id = t2.id FOR XML RAW('a')) sub(c)
WHERE sub.c LIKE '%"I"%';
```

Output:

```
┌────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ ID │ Name │ Status │ Address │ Phone │
├────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼───────┤
│  1 │ Tom  │ I      │ U       │ D     │
│  3 │ Pam  │ D      │ I       │ U     │
└────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=a2e8bf7a11b8b356f8f53bc237ac3938)**

---

## EDIT:

A bit more advanced option that excludes some columns. Basically simulating  [`SELECT * EXCEPT id, name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413819/select-except):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CAST((SELECT t.* for XML RAW) AS xml))) B(XMLData)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 c
             FROM B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  AS C1(n)
             CROSS APPLY C1.n.nodes('./@*') AS C2(a)
             WHERE a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') NOT IN ('id','name')
               AND a.value('.','varchar(max)')  = 'I') C;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=5225cd4800e6b87fc554463a03dff74f)**

Comment: What if row with `ID=2` has `Address` field equal to `RIDGE RD. 32`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Nothing. **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=2935f61dd62043eafd58dc4e17340c70)**

Comment: Ok, then something like `R. "I". RD. 32`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Still nothing. What are you trying to accomplish? [Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1fcfa1c83958793f0097811292f18777)

Comment: I'm just trying to critically assess your answer. Asking questions is one way to do so. There are no bad intentions ...

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Feel free to play with my demo - it is interactive :) Of course it will return row if name is `I` if you seek counterexamples(but I could make a version that simulate [`SELECT * EXCEPT name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413819/select-except)).

Comment: Thanks @LukaszSzozda - this query really works for me! but I don't understand what sub(c) does there and couldn't find any relevant information from Google. Could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: sub(c) is just an alias for subquery and column. Subquery builds XML [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=b97b38aea161eb146e57f8f323471b89)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way of doing your query without making *any* mention of column names.  Here is one method which uses a string concatenation trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CONCAT(Status, Address, Phone) LIKE '%I%';
```

[image]

### Demo

I don't think it is too difficult to list out 20 column names, once, in a query.  If you need a way to get all columns from a table in SQL Server, then [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/how-do-you-return-the-column-names-of-a-table).

Comment: *`"I need a query that does not specify the column names"`*

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen - but my real table has dozens of columns so I definitely won't explicitly list all those columns in my query.

Comment: @sopint If you really have this many columns, then you should use dynamic SQL to build the query.  Then, your current logic is just fine.  If you can write out the columns, my answer is one option.

Comment: There is one downside of this approach. If column can contain more than one character you won't be able to distinguish `'I'` from `'IA'` at least not without some kind of separator like `WHERE CONCAT(Status,'^', Address,'^' ,Phone) LIKE '%^I^%';`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda You're right, and I knew this when I posted, but the OP does seem to only have single letters.  But this does the job of having to check only once for all columns, versus having to check every column.