# Sort Column names alphabetically in a table

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, we get the table description using below command:

```
Sp_help TableName
```

When it displays all column names in a random order. Is there a way If I want to get all column names alphabetically sorted in some order (Descending or Ascending)?

This will help me to have a quick look at the table to see what all columns are present and whether a specific column is present in the table or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you return the column names of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/how-do-you-return-the-column-names-of-a-table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may get the List of Column from the System View which is  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. You can do a Select on the View and Filter by Table there order the List based on any of your desired values as mentioned below:

```
SELECT  
    *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME ='YourTableName'
        ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

There is one more query to achieve this:

```
SELECT  * 
        FROM    sys.COLUMNS where object_id = OBJECT_ID('yourtablename') 
        ORDER   By NAME
```

Comment: instead of using the IN clause, you can Just use WHERE [Object_id] = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName')

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh Thank you for the comments. Edited my answer as per suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Oops, other answer just beat me, and mine is in table order not alphabetical order. But look at Information_schema and you can do whatever you want.

Use information_schema.

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='yourtable' order by ordinal_position
```

Comment: I wanted to sort alphabetically by column names, so I cannot sort by Ordinal_position.