# Is it possible to use pattern matching in SQL query to reduce the name of columns returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going to write some custom code to reduce the length of the columns returned. It is just that I wanted to know if it is possible to do it when I get the data itself.

For example the query returns:
SELECT * FROM sillytable

| This_part_always_remains_same_for_all_columns_Date | This_part_always_remains_same_for_all_columns_Value |
| --- | --- |
| 18/01/2021 | 34 |
| 17/01/2021 | 45 |

Is there something I can do in the query that it returns

| Manf_Date | Manf_Value |
| --- | --- |
| 18/01/2021 | 34 |
| 17/01/2021 | 45 |

Essentially I want to replace the **This_part_always_remains_same_for_all_columns** with **Manf** in the results returned.

Comment: Don't do `select *` in the first place, alias every column with a short name. Better, give columns short names to start with (but not too short)

Comment: You need to use an explicit `as` to assign the columns new names.

Comment: This table has 100+ column names. And that can change in future. :'-(

Comment: Why do you have a **100 column** table?

Comment: @NotAgainsaysReinstateMonica You said you were going to write code. So get started. Nothing will automatically do that for you. One workaround is to create a view to do that - and yes that will also require some repetitive coding. You might be able to use dynamic sql to generate the DDL for each view that removes the repeating bits.

Comment: @SMor Yes I am already working on custom code on the client side to make it a bit more manageable.

Comment: @Charlieface The table is simply getting created by Kepware server pumping sensor data into the table. I do not have much control over it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to dynamic SQL than you could do this:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) 
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + 
              string_agg(name + ' as ' + 
              replace(name, 'This_part_always_remains_same_for_all_columns', 'Manf_'), ',') + 
             ' FROM SillyTable'
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('sillytable')

exec(@sql)
```

This returns:

```
Manf__Date  Manf__Value
2021-01-18  34
2021-01-17  45
```

Though I'm not sure why you wouldn't change the column names in the table.

Comment: The data is getting pumped into table via Kepware. I do not have much control over the column names.

Comment: Does this answer your question though? on the column name issues, 2 approaches, rename the columns and add a view which gives the names required by kepware, or keep the column names but add a view to shorten the names. You could use a variation of my script to create the views. Of course the other approach is to change how the columns are displayed in your front-end code.

Comment: I ended up writing custom code to change the names of columns after the data pull.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can alias the column names in the `select` statement with `as`:

```
select
   This_part_always_remains_same_for_all_columns_Date as [Manf_Date],
   This_part_always_remains_same_for_all_columns_Value as [Manf_Value]
from sillytable
```

Comment: This table has 100+ column names. And that can change in future. :'-(

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to get all the columns of this table to a new table,
look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/how-do-you-return-the-column-names-of-a-table) for a sample .
Now you have a temp table with
This_part_always_remains_same_for_all_columns

and then
_date
_value
_time

so use [REPLACE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp) function (or other string manipulation) to achieve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I will preface by saying: you probably shouldn't have 100 column tables, and you very rarely should be using `select *` on a table anyway.

Be that as it may, here is a neat solution using dynamic SQL. We just concatenate all the columns together, then execute a select:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
(
SELECT N'SELECT ' +
    STRING_AGG(CAST(
        c.name + N' AS ' + REPLACE(c.name, 'This_part_always_remains_same_for_all_columns', 'Manf') AS nvarchar(max))
    , ', ') +
    N' FROM sillytable;'
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tablename')
);

EXEC(@sql);
```