# How can I get column names from a table in SQL?

Tags: sql

[image]

i want result -> Student_id,Name,Address,Marks

Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: The ANSI/ISO SQL standard has INFORMATION_SCHEMA! Here you can do `select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'Student'` .

Comment: @Abra, my comment is mainly a response to "Metadata is not part of standard SQL", INFORMATION_SCHEMA _is_ standard SQL. (Besides, the <sql> tag says "_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._")

Comment: i use Prestashop, Database/SQL Manager

Comment: Prestashop, does that imply MySQL?

Comment: Column names are referred to as [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata). While standard SQL defines [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema), not every RDBMS implements it. However, most RDBMS's have a [data dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary). You need to tell us which database you are using in order for us to tell you how to access the data dictionary. Are you using MySQL? Are you using SQL Server? Are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: I don't know exactly and I use a database with Hostinger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL, MS SQL and Postgresql (thanks @christophe)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_name'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

PIVOT the results if you need column names in one line

Comment: For Postgresql : 
```sql
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
   AND table_name   = 'your_table'
     ;
```

Comment: yes. but I'm not sure whether MS SQL has a TABLE_SCHEMA column. I don't have MS SQL SERVER to check.

Comment: i have this error -> The "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" table does not exist.

Comment: Yes, it's in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/how-do-you-return-the-column-names-of-a-table)

Comment: @OmarChakroun whats your db?

Comment: it's working when I tested in PHPMyAdmin but it's doesn't work in my Site Web.

Comment: may be you don't have the permission to information_schema database?

Comment: The comparison chart at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance lists products having INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

Comment: Erreur de syntaxe près de '.COLUMNS

Comment: no problem with Sql query. Better raise a another question with your code which causes the error. tag me if you wish in that question. better leave a up vote so this can help others

Comment: This does not work in SQL Server, to make it work there this line `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'`should be changed to `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_name'`

Answer (score 3):

If you have several other columns and want to display some of them, then use :

```
SELECT Student_id, Name, Address, Marks
FROM Student
```

Otherwise, if you only have these 4 columns in your table, then :

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
```

If you only want the names of your columns without data, then :

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE 1=0
/*or*/
SELECT Student_id, Name, Address, Marks FROM Student WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: I just want the name of column.

Comment: The 2 possibilities will display what you want

Comment: it returns all data but I want just the names of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you the column names, if that's what you're looking for.

```
select *
from table
where 1=2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<%

Dim rs1, i

Set rs1 = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )

set rs1 = yourconnection.execute( "SELECT * FROM Student" )

For i=0 to rs1.Fields.Count-1 

      Response.Write rs1.fields(i).name  & ", "  
             
Next
 
%>
```

---

you will get: Student_id, Name, Address, Marks

Comment: This would be a good answer to "how to get column names in ASP", but the question in this case is "how to get column names in SQL"

Comment: You are right. It's just I was looking for the same answer in ASP and when finally figured it out, decided to share it here as it's the closest question I saw. Maybe someone will find it helpful.